# How to know if a given prinicapl Id is group or a user

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have list of principal id which I know have a specific role eligibility. Now I need to get the user info like user name and email if the principal type is user else get all transitive members name and email if the principal type is group.
I am thinking of first getting the directory Objects by Ids (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0) and then doing List group transitive members(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) if the directory object is graph.

Let me know if there is a more optimized way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not very sure if the API is updated or not, I remembered that the API would return the `Directory Object` as an response and it contains property like this `"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",` to show you if this object is a user/group, you might check your API response. I mean the first API link you shared. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHmDa.png

Comment: @TinyWang yes this is correct, the api returns the type in response. I was mainly looking for if there is any other more effective way of doing what i am doing

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used below **PowerShell script** to know whether principal Id is **user** or **group** and get their display name and mail :

```
Connect-AzureAD
$principalIds = "xxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxx"
foreach ($principalId in $principalIds) {
    
    $directoryObject = Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectIds $principalId
    if ($directoryObject.ObjectType -eq "User") {

        $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $principalId | Select-Object DisplayName, Mail
        Write-Host "Principal ID -> User: $principalId`nUser Name: $($user.DisplayName)`nUser Email: $($user.Mail)"
        Write-Host
    }
    elseif ($directoryObject.ObjectType -eq "Group") {

        $group = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $principalId
        Write-Host "Principal ID -> Group: $principalId`nGroup Name: $($group.DisplayName)"
        Write-Host

        $groupMembers = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $principalId 
        foreach ($member in $groupMembers) {
            $memberInfo = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member.ObjectId | Select-Object DisplayName, Mail
            Write-Host "Group Member Name: $($memberInfo.DisplayName)`nGroup Member Email: $($memberInfo.Mail)"
        }
        Write-Host
    }
}
```

I have one Azure AD group named **`SriGroup`** with members like below:

[image]

When I ran the script by including above **`groupID`** in $principalIds, I got response with **display name** and **mail** successfully like below:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$principalIds = "48d7c662-d602-42d2-bc16-xxxxxxxxx", "0c5c5ffe-527a-4cf2-8362-xxxxxxxx", "7488bc42-6a7c-4ba2-a4c3-xxxxxxxxxx"

foreach ($principalId in $principalIds) {
    
    $directoryObject = Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectIds $principalId
    if ($directoryObject.ObjectType -eq "User") {

        $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $principalId | Select-Object DisplayName, Mail
        Write-Host "Principal ID -> User: $principalId`nUser Name: $($user.DisplayName)`nUser Email: $($user.Mail)"
        Write-Host
    }
    elseif ($directoryObject.ObjectType -eq "Group") {

        $group = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $principalId
        Write-Host "Principal ID -> Group: $principalId`nGroup Name: $($group.DisplayName)"
        Write-Host

        $groupMembers = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $principalId 
        foreach ($member in $groupMembers) {
            $memberInfo = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member.ObjectId | Select-Object DisplayName, Mail
            Write-Host "Group Member Name: $($memberInfo.DisplayName)`nGroup Member Email: $($memberInfo.Mail)"
        }
        Write-Host
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]